# Is there way to provide wrapper of ParseTree to antlr4 parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there way to provide wrapper of ParseTree to antlr4 parser?

In antlr2 I could set custom AST node type :

```
parser.setASTNodeClass(DetailAST.class.getName());
```

I know that in antlr4 there is no AST, but I want to add some functionality to all nodes in parse tree, for example: getNextSibling, getPreviousSibling, getType, getLine, getColumn, etc.

I don't want cast every node to YYYContext to work with it. Instead of this I want to create basic class for all nodes in parse tree that will have all these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ANTLR 4.4, there is no way to override the types used for the parse tree. An issue does exist for discussions on the subject, but (as of today) the feature has not been implemented or even assigned to a target release milestone.

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/30